# Has anyone managed to shoehorn the Welcome Page from Delphi XE2 into Delphi 10.2 Tokyo?

Tags: javascript, delphi

Specifically I'm looking at the whole **Manage Favourites** that **XE2** supported but that is inexplicitly gone from the "newer" versions of the IDE.

Looking at the *default.htm* file supplied with **10.2 Tokyo** that is used to render the **Welcome Page**, I can see this code snippet:

```
function makeFavorite(id)
{
var to_copy = $('#' + id);
var fileName = to_copy.attr('title');

if (external.Application) 
{
    var newID = external.Application.AddToFavorites(fileName);
    if (newID != -1)
    {
    var item = formatProjectItem(newID, fileName, 'favorite');
    $('#block4').append(item);
    $('#favorite-projects').parent().show();
    resizePanels();
    }
    else
    {
    alert('This element is already in the favorite list');
    }
}
}
```

**XE2** has a number of separate JavaScript files (*manageFavorites.js, projectActions.js and projectLoader.js*), the last of which has this equivalent function:

```
function makeProjectFavorite(favLink, projectFile) {
    var groupNode;
    var projectNode;

    try {
        groupNode = getSubNodeEx(xmlProjectFavorites.documentElement, "group", "default", "1");
        if (groupNode.selectSingleNode("@title") == null) {
            setAttrValue(groupNode, "title", getLangString("newFavorites"));
        }
        projectNode = getSubNodeEx(groupNode, "project", "location", projectFile);
        saveFavoritesList();
        reloadProjects(true);
        loadMyFavoritesList();
    } catch(e) {
        debugAlert("makeProjectFavorite: " + e.message);
    }
}
```

Crucially, there IS a *manageFavorites.js* in the **10.2** folder (and also in the **10.4 Sydney** folder too), but the *default.htm* does not include it, however the *projectLoader.js* supplied with **10.2** does include the `makeProjectFavorite` function used by **XE2**, so theoretically it should be possible to re-implement the **Manage Favorites** functionality on the **Welcome Page**.

I just don't know enough HTML or Javascript to do it myself, but has someone else done it? Or poked Embarcadero to do it?

Comment: I don't have an XE2 install on hand. What functionality does Manage Favorites give you that you don't get with the Favorites functionality on the later version Welcome pages? You can add and delete favorites in 10.4, what else do you want to do?

Comment: @LachlanG XE2 also has ability to crate favorite groups, so it is easier to organize and locate projects.

Comment: There is Welcome Page plugin for Sydney provided by MVP Daniel Wolf that has better organizational functionality https://www.danielwolf.eu/blog/2015/1668-meine-vorstellung-einer-willkommens-seite

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar That seems like a useful plugin. I'll give it a go. Just a shame that the default Welcome Page doesn't include the ability to handle favorite groups, even though most of the Javascript code is still included with the IDE.

Comment: @DalijaPrasnikar: Thanks for that link. I've been complaining about the redesign of the Favorites implementation since it disappeared, and this plugin looks like it will help considerably. Shame that the source isn't available - I'd buy it if it was for sure.